# Populating Dropdown using jquery from json data

Tags: jquery, json

I have following JSON Data

```
{"Date Created":"date_entered","Date Modified":"date_modified","Description":"description"}
```

How do I populate dropdown with jquery using this json data ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming data has already been parsed to javascript object, you need to loop over object keys and construct html something like:

```
var html='<option value=""></option>';
for(key in data){
    html += '<option value="' + data[key] + '">' + key + '</option>';
}
$('#mySelect').html( html );
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vk5mx8ct/)**</kbd>

Comment: Great solution. Helped me beyond my need.